# Solr relevancy using edismax

Tags: search, solr, relevance, edismax

How to add edismax in solr config to give my title boosting then description then facets and so on...

My solr config looks like this

```
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
<str name="qf">text^50 and title^1000 and contentdescription^180 and productname^140 and groupname^13 and maincontent^113 and contenttype^120 and published_date^115 and viewcount^114 and fileid^101 and filename^10 and content^10</str>
 <str name="pf">text^50 and title^1000 and contentdescription^180 and productname^140 and groupname^13 and maincontent^113 and contenttype^120 and published_date^115 and viewcount^114 and fileid^101 and filename^10 and content^10</str>
```

and

schema as

```
<copyField source="id" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="productid" dest="text"/>
     <copyField source="groupid" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="maincontent" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="title" dest="text" />
   <copyField source="contentdescription" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="groupname" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="productname" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="videourl" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="contenttype" dest="text" />
<copyField source="title" dest="autocomplete-field" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just a couple of things to check...

1. Remove all the 'and's from the qf, and pf, the list of field names are just separated by a space, should look something like this:

> text^50 title^1000 contentdescription^180 productname^140 groupname^13 maincontent^113 contenttype^120 published_date^115 viewcount^114 fileid^101 filename^10 content^10

2. Make sure that all the fields you include in the qf, and pf are indexed (with option indexed="true" in the field definitions)